# Form Ajax in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new in Rails.

I'm trying to add a form with ajax.It's just typing a text and submit to file 'ex/act' and show the param in form.

My code:

```
 <script>
    function loadDoc(url, cfunc) {
      var xhttp;
      xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
          cfunc(xhttp);
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
    function myFunction(xhttp) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
</script>
```

And the form:

```
<%= form_for :ex,url:ex_act_path,remote:true do |f|%>
    <%= f.text_field :text%>
    <button onclick="loadDoc('ex/act',myFunction)">abc</button>
<%end%>
```

In the 'ex/act' controller:

```
def act
    @a = get_param
end
private
 def get_param
    params.require(:ex).permit(:text)
 end
```

In the Console of browser:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/ex/act 422 Unprocessable Entity
GET http://localhost:3000/ex/act 200 OK
```

It doesn't show anything when I submit.

Comment: Have you tried looking at `log/development.log` in your Rails application?

Comment: No,I havent.Im new in Rails,so I dont know how to check errors

Comment: If you use the command line in OSX or Linux, try going to the directory of the Rails application, and typing in `less -R log/development.log`

Comment: I did it,It shows many things

Comment: Is that good, or bad?

Comment: It's so long. (191.3ms)  CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" varchar NOT NULL) 
   (0.1ms)  select sqlite_version(*)
   (133.1ms)  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "unique_schema_migrations" ON "schema_migratio
ns" ("version")
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM 
"schema_migrations"
Migrating to CreateTaskes (20160222034126)

Comment: try using tail -f log/development.log on separate terminal. then monitor it while you send the POST ajax